# Calculate the area of the triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Here is a cute little problem.

In the diagram below $ABC$ is a right triangle, $\angle ABC$ is a right angle. The blue region inside the triangle is a rectangle. Given that point $G$ is both a corner of the rectangle and the centroid of the triangle, and that the area of the blue region is $24$ unit square, find the area of the triangle.

[image]

(Below is one possible approach. Can you come up with something different?)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @blackened I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show us your trying.

Comment: Technically, the blue region need only be a parallelogram in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelRozenberg has answered the post already. I am just adding the details.

The ratios dividing the lines are as shown.

[image]

[X] = … = 12

[Y] = [X]/2 = 6

Also, $[Y] = (\dfrac {1}{1+2})^2 \times [\triangle ABD] = \dfrac 19 \times (\dfrac 12 [\triangle ABC])$

Then, $[\triangle ABC]) = ....$

Answer (score 0):

$$\Delta ABC=\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot BC=\frac{9}{2}\cdot\frac{AB}{3}\cdot\frac{BC}{3}=\frac{9}{2}\cdot24=108.$$

Comment: So how do you know the sides of the triangles divided in thirds?  Do not answer in Comments, please add this explanation to the answer.